# Why is my error styling and ajax redirect not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My signup form is working perfectly as the data is being passed and checked by the signup.inc.php file but visually it is not displaying the error styling and after the form is successfully validated and the user is added, it does not redirect the user to profile.php. can anyone help me understand? Thanks in advance.

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yahbang</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#signup-form").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var first = $("#signup-first").val();
                var last = $("#signup-last").val();
                var email = $("#signup-email").val();
                var pwd = $("#signup-pwd").val();
                var submit = $("#signup-submit").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'include/signup.inc.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {first: first, last: last, email: email, pwd: pwd, submit: submit},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(respond){

                    if(!respond.status)
                    {
                        alert(respond.message);
                    }
                    else
                        Window.Location.href = respond.redirect;
                    }
        });  
    });
});



</script>

</head>
<body>
<header>

    <div class="header_index">
            <div class="headerlogo">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Yahbang</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>


                <form id="login-form" class="loginform" action='include/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                        <input  id="login-email" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
                        <input  id="login-pwd" type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
                        <p><a href="forgotpassword.php">Forgot Password</a></p>
                        <button id="login-submit" type='submit'>Login</button>
                        <p class="login-message"></p>
                    </form>



</header>


                <form id="signup-form" class="signup" action='include/signup.inc.php' method='POST'>
                    <input id="signup-first" type='text' name='first' placeholder='First Name'><br>
                    <input id="signup-last" type='text' name='last' placeholder='Last Name'><br>
                    <input id="signup-email" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'><br>
                    <input id="signup-pwd" type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'><br>
                    <button id="signup-submit" type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
                    <p class="signup-message"></p>
                </form>





<footer>
    <div class="footer_index">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="TermsofUse.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

signup.inc.php:

```
<?php  
session_start();
include '../dbh.php';

    $respond = array(
    'status'   => true,
    'message'  => 'There was an error',
    'redirect' => '../profile.php'
);


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $last = $_POST['last'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;



if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($pwd)) {
    echo "<span class='signup-error'>Please fill out all fields!</span>";
    $errorEmpty = true;
    }

elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<span class='signup-error'>Please enter a valid email address!</span>";
    $errorEmail = true;
    } 


else {
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);



if ($emailcheck > 0) {
    echo "<span class='signup-error'>That email address already exists!</span>";
    $errorEmail = true;
    echo json_encode($respond);
    }



else {
    $encryptpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (first, last, email, pwd)
    VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$encryptpwd')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }

}
}
?>


<script> 
$("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").removeClass("input-error");

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";
    var errorEmail = "<?php echo $errorEmail; ?>"; 

 if (errorEmpty == true) {
  $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").addClass("input-error");
 }

 if (errorEmail == true) {
  $("#signup-email").addClass("input-error");
 } 

 if (errorEmpty == false && errorEmail == false) {
  $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").val("");
}

 </script>
```

Comment: What error styling are you talking about? And have you tried the redirect as `window.location.href`? Might be case-sensitive.

Comment: the error styling is located at the bottom of the signup.inc.php file in the script tags.

Comment: Also, I think the following is considered better practice: `document.location.assign(respond.redirect)`

Comment: If you are just dumping a block of HTML to the ajax request, it won't get loaded into the current page. Think of your signup.inc.php as a phone operator: the ajax function makes the call, the server-side script gives a response directly to the ajax function (the `respond` bit you are parsing to determine what to do next), and the ajax function parses the response and deals with the follow up logic. The server-side script doesn't just dump things back to the entire page when called, nor would you want it to, right? You should have the script already in the page....

Comment: and then have it be tied to some response from the ajax function. Also, I can almost guarantee you this is why your redirect is failing, because the ajax function isn't getting a parsable response. Remove the non-php part of that script and the redirect will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't just dump a full script back in an ajax request and expect it to work. The request is handled by the ajax function, not just glued to the bottom of the current page.

In your case, your script could be moved to the main `index.php` and called by the ajax callback function. For example:

```
if(!respond.status)
{
    alert(respond.message);
    showErrors(respond.errorEmpty, respond.errorEmail);
}
```

The above assumes a couple of things. Firstly, that you would change-up that current script slightly to be a callable function, ie:

```
function showErrors(errorEmpty, errorEmail) {
    $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").removeClass("input-error");

     if (errorEmpty == true) {
      $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").addClass("input-error");
     }

     if (errorEmail == true) {
      $("#signup-email").addClass("input-error");
     } 

     if (errorEmpty == false && errorEmail == false) {
      $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").val("");
    }
}
```

Now this `showErrors` function can go in your main index.php script, so that the ajax function can call it as needed.

Second, it assumes you are passing those `$errorEmpty` and `$errorEmail` variables in php back to the ajax request in the response, similar to your other response variables. Something like:

```
$respond = array(
    'status'   => true,
    'message'  => 'There was an error',
    'redirect' => '../profile.php',
    'errors',
);

if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($pwd)) {

    $respond['errors'][] = "Please fill out all fields!";
    $respond['errorEmpty'] = true;

} elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    $respond['errors'][] = "Please enter a valid email address!";
    $respond['errorEmail'] = true;

} else {

    $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($emailcheck > 0) {
        $respond['errors'][] = "That email address already exists!";
        $respond['errorEmail'] = true;

        echo json_encode($respond);

    }
```

So now you can pass `respond.errorEmpty` to the error handling function.

Comment: thanks much for this. i'm learning to code and this is so great.

Comment: I fudged with some other stuff too, as you may notice. You shouldn't be echoing out the errors either. But how you want to handle them when passed back to the ajax request, I've left to you. I think you could also consider leveraging the input elements `:valid` state for styling, but I also think it's a good habit to have your inputs get checked on the server side (as well as on the client side) and returning some error (even if it isn't involved in styling).

Comment: probably a dumb question but should I insert the showErrors function directly above the $(document).ready(function()?  sorry still learning.

Comment: Doesn't need to be directly above. Or above at all (since it will be loaded by the time the ajax function needs it).